# The interface code is giving compile time error

Tags: java

```
interface I1 {
    int i = 10;
    void add();
    void sub();
    void del();
}
interface I2 {
    void disp();
}
class A implements I1,I2 {
    void add(){...}
    void sub(){...}
    void del(){...}
    void disp(){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This code is giving compile time error. I don't know what is the wrong with this code.

Comment: If you read the compiler error messages, that would be great...

Comment: Just check the compiler's error message

Comment: Please tell me you don't actually have `...` in your code.  With this question I'm forced to wonder!

Answer (score 9):

Implicitly, `I1.add()` et al are public. Therefore in your class you must also make them public:

```
public void add(){...}
public void sub(){...}
public void del(){...}
public void disp(){
    System.out.printf(i);
}
```

Otherwise you'd get

```
Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from test.I1
```

Also, the call to [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) needs to change to:

```
System.out.printf("%d", i);
```

(The first argument is a format string.)

Comment: Sadly, OP couldn't get this since he/she never read the compiler error messages =\

Comment: and about `i` that _i_ just mentioned in my answer

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I don't understand why you'd have to explicitly qualify `i` with `I1`. My compiler is happy with just `i` (and I don't see why it wouldn't be).

Answer (score 4):

can't  narrow down the visibility as @NPE mentioned and

`i` is `public static final` by default so access it by

```
I1.i
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you'd have to use the fully-qualified name. My compiler is happy with plain `i`, and I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: to avoid confusion (it will compile fine eitherway)

Answer (score 2):

All methods in an interface default to public.

See [Java Language Specification 6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) which states

```
All members of interfaces are implicitly public.
```

And you can't reduce the visibility of the methods when overriding them. You need to make them public.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use printf without using the format.

System.out.printf("%i", i);

would most likely allow you to do that, but without the format, it might not always work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jigar Joshi Answer,

[Why are interface variables static and final by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430756/why-are-interface-variables-static-and-final-by-default)

If you are using JDK above 1.4,

You can use static import;
e.g.

```
  import static packagename.I1.*;
```

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/what-is-static-import-in-java-5-example-tutorial.html

Comment: If you are not using a JDK above 1.4, then I'd like to welcome you to the [21st century...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29)

Answer (score 0):

You can not reduce the visibility of inherited method. Inside interface, all variables and methods are by default `public`.

```
interface I1 {
    int i = 10;
    void add();
    void sub();
    void del();
}

interface I2 {
    void disp();
}

public class B implements I1,I2 {
    public void add(){}
    public void sub(){}
    public void del(){}
    public void disp(){
         System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```