# How to provide dynamic configration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to do a dynamic injection of class in production. suppose we have one interface as Shape which provides an implementation for two classes namely Rectangle and Triangle.

for some classes, I want to provide Triangle instance and for some classes, I want to provide a Rectangle class instance.

So question is how to do this in Spring Boot

```
interface Shape{
}

class Rectangle implements Shape{
}


class Triangel implements Shape{
}
```

Comment: Spring boot is same as Java only, is this your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - interfaces and implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111451/spring-boot-interfaces-and-implementations)

Comment: you are not forced to use the spring container, you can create your instance yourself

Comment: you can go with `@Qualifier` or `@Profile` or `@Conditional`..  [you can find @condition here](https://javapapers.com/spring/spring-conditional-annotation/) .

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

If you know at Compile time which implementation of `Shape` Class You want to inject then  You can use  `@Qualifier` Annotation. You can Find number of examples for this.

IF You want to inject Bean based on certain properties which can change at run time, Then You can use `@Conditional` `Annotations`. You will also find examples for this.