# Data hiding in interface java

Tags: java, interface, data-hiding

```
    interface My{
        int x = 10;
    }
    class Temp implements My{
        int x = 20;
        public static void main(String[] s){
              System.out.println(new Temp().x);
        }
    }
```

This prints the result as 20. Is there any way that I can access the x that belongs to the interface in the class?

Comment: Why would you put data in an interface. Wouldn't an abstract class be better suited for this purpose?

Comment: I was studying interfaces so this situation came into my mind and maybe I would do so because interfaces are lightweight compared to abstract classes.

Comment: consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430756/why-are-interface-variables-static-and-final-by-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do an explicit cast to the interface type:

```
System.out.println(((My)new Temp()).x);
```

Note however that `x` is not bound to any instance of `My`. Interface fields are implicitly `static` and `final` (more of constants), meaning the above can be done using:

```
System.out.println(My.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this.

```
interface My {

    int x = 10;
}

class Temp implements My {

    int x = 20;

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        System.out.println(new Temp().x);        // 20
        System.out.println(My.x);                // 10
    }
}
```

fields of an `Interface` are always `static.`