# Difference between the terms "Instance variable" and "variables declared in Interfaces"

Tags: java, variables, interface, instance-variables, member-variables

I was reading about Interfaces in a Book and I came upon this Line that confused me.

> Interfaces are syntactically similar to classes, but they lack instance variables.

As far as I know about `Interfaces`, we can define variables inside an Interface which are by default `final`.

My question is, What does that `Line` mean? and What is the Difference between an `Instance Variable` and the `Variable defined in the Interface`??

Comment: I think that it points to the fact that you can not have an instance of an Interface, and therefor you'll never have an instance variable in an interface.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, What does that Line mean?

Amongst other things, it means the book's terminology is off. By "instance variable," they mean "instance field."

An *instance field* is a field that is specific to an individual instance of a class. For example:

```
class Foo {
    // Instance field:
    private int bar;

    // Static field:
    public static final int staticBar;
}
```

The field `bar` is per-instance, not class-wide. The field `staticBar` is class-wide (a *static* field, sometimes called a "class field").

Interfaces don't have instance fields. They do have *static* fields. When you do this:

```
interface FooInterface {
    int staticBar;
}
```

`staticBar` is automatically declared `public`, `static`, and `final` (per JLS [§9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3)). So that `staticBar` is roughly equivalent to the one on our `Foo` class before.

Answer (score 1):

This means you cant have instance variable but a constant static final variable within an interface as per [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html). For e.g.

```
interface MyIface {
    public static final int MY_CONSTANT = 1;
}
```

And access it using interface name like:

```
int variable = MyIface.MY_CONSTANT;
```