# How to access Java Interface Static variable after converted to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a an Interface in Java with the static variable `interfaceValue` that I could access as below

```
public class Experimenting {

    public interface MyInteface {
        int interfaceValue = 10;
    }

    class MyImpl implements MyInteface { }

    MyImpl myImpl = new MyImpl();

    void testing() {
        int getInterfaceValue = myImpl.interfaceValue;
    }
}
```

When I convert to Kotlin, it is as below

```
class Experimenting {

    internal var myImpl = MyImpl()

    interface MyInteface {
        companion object {
            val interfaceValue = 10
        }
    }

    internal inner class MyImpl : MyInteface

    internal fun testing() {
        val getInterfaceValue = myImpl.interfaceValue
    }
}
```

However the `myImpl.interfaceValue` is showing compile error sign, where by it doesn't recognize the `interfaceValue`. How could I still access my `interfaceValue` in Kotlin?

Comment: declare variables in interface is ugly and bad practice

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I'm just experimenting the language feature.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion converts the [static final `interfaceValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430756/why-are-interface-variables-static-and-final-by-default) to a `val` in the `companion` Kotlins equivalent of that. Unfortunately the converter is not perfect and sometimes messes thing up. To access it

```
import com.your.package.Experimenting.MyInteface.Companion.interfaceValue    
class Experimenting {

    internal var myImpl = MyImpl()

    interface MyInteface {
        companion object {
           const val interfaceValue = 10
        }
    }

    internal inner class MyImpl : MyInteface

    internal fun testing() {
        val getInterfaceValue = interfaceValue
    } 
}
```

does the trick.

also does:

```
class Experimenting {

    internal var myImpl = MyImpl()

    interface MyInteface {
        companion object {
           val interfaceValue = 10
        }
    }

    internal inner class MyImpl : MyInteface

    internal fun testing() {
        val getInterfaceValue = MyInteface.interfaceValue
    }
}
```

A third way would be to copy the value of `interfaceValue` into the implementing class:

```
class Experimenting {

    internal var myImpl = MyImpl()

    interface MyInteface {
        companion object {
            const val interfaceValue = 10
        }
    }

    internal inner class MyImpl : MyInteface{
        val interfaceValue = MyInteface.interfaceValue
    }

    internal fun testing() {
        val getInterfaceValue = myImpl.interfaceValue
    }
}
```

Basically you access it like you would access a static variable in java.

Comment: Thanks. I like your answer, but that makes the `interfaceValue` no longer accessible from the implementor, which makes it different from what it was originally intended. I still give you a vote for the syntactically correctness of it. Thanks!

Comment: I have another answer, which I think mimic the original behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52978332/3286489 Do check it out and let me think what your thought is. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer loosens the constraints on `interfaceValue` from `final` to `open`. Also It will no longer be static.

Comment: Agree, it is no longer syntatically correct. Though it is not final, it is not mutable too. Hence in practical, the usage would be more similar to the original Java version.

Comment: `final` in the sense that you cannot override or change it. You can not change the value of `interfaceValue` in the java interface either

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right conversion of such Java code to Kotlin code should be as below

```
class Experimenting {

    internal var myImpl = MyImpl()

    interface MyInteface {

        val interfaceValue: Int
        get() = 10
    }

    internal inner class MyImpl : MyInteface

    internal fun testing() {
        val getInterfaceValue = myImpl.interfaceValue
    }
}
```

Though syntactically they are different, i.e. `interfaceValue` not really a static variable anymore, but practicality the same.

Comment: What this lets you do is override the `interfaceValue`. If this is what you want go for it. It really depends if the `interfaceValue` is constant for all `MyInterface`s (my answer and the behaviout as it is in java) or should be able to be overridden (this).

Comment: consider `internal inner class MyMyImpl : MyInteface{
        override val interfaceValue : Int
        get() = 11
    }`

Comment: I see, one could override it. You have the point, that the subtle different.

Comment: This is the kind of difference that causes hard to fix bugs. So if you do this do not assume it to be equal to the java code.

Comment: I guess in short Java != Kotlin, and Kotlin != Java. Both have its pro con.

Comment: I just noticed you can shadow the interface property in Java. So yeah, this comes closer to the Java version. But you can also do that in Kotlin

Comment: Can you provide more detail of what you mean?

Comment: ` internal inner class MyImpl : MyInteface{
        val interfaceValue = 0
    }

    internal fun testing() {
        val getInterfaceValue = myImpl.interfaceValue
    }`