# Java variable in interface in Kotlin way

Tags: java, kotlin

I am interesting are there any way to replace kotlin interface variable in Java.

E.g. what should i write in java to have same logic

```
interface ObjectWithId
{
    var id : Long
}
```

Before facing this problem all my code could be easily converted back to java, but using interface variables breaks 'backward compatibility'. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not clear if you're asking how to create an implementation of this specific interface in your Java code, or how to define an interface in Java with the same functionality as this one.

Comment: One helpful site for these question. It provides a kotlin compiler + java disassembler https://javap.yawk.at/#O0tyIG/procyon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java this interface would be:

```
public interface ObjectWithId {
    long getId();        
    void setId(long p0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, and also i should have some variable in 'implementer' to store id?

Comment: This is the correct answer, the `var` or `val` in Kotlin are not actually variables, but properties (a setter, getter and backing field joined together). Interfaces are not supposed to hold state, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430756/why-are-interface-variables-static-and-final-by-default).

Comment: @Bios90 thats open for the implementor, how this property is implemented. Most common would be a private field.