# why compiler says a public static field in interface is "final" although it is not

Tags: java, interface, static

Please see the below code --

```
public interface TestInterface {
    public static String NON_CONST_B = "" ; 
}

public class Implemented implements TestInterface {
    public static String NON_CONST_C = "" ;
}

public class AutoFinal  {

    public static String NON_CONST_A = "" ;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestInterface.NON_CONST_B = "hello-b" ;
        Implemented.NON_CONST_C = "hello-c";
        AutoFinal.NON_CONST_A = "hello-a" ;
        Implemented obj = new Implemented();
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains that `TestInterface.NON_CONST_B` is final --

```
AutoFinal.java:6: error: cannot assign a value to final variable NON_CONST_B
        TestInterface.NON_CONST_B = "hello-b" ;
                 ^
1 error
```

why ?

Comment: All fields in an interface are `public static final` by default just as all methods are `public abstract` by default.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, As of Java 8, methods can have `default` implementation (non-`abstract`). See: https://www.journaldev.com/2389/java-8-features-with-examples#interface-default-static-method. (Also `static` methods are allowed).

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili In Java 1 to 18.3 the default modifiers for methods are `public abstract` but if you add `default` as a keyword to the method from Java 8 you can give it a `public` *default* implementation ;) Java 9 allows `private` methods to be added to interfaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding:

```
public interface TestInterface {
   public static String NON_CONST_B = "" ; 
}

public class AutoFinal  {    
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      TestInterface.NON_CONST_B = "hello-b" ;
      // ....
   }
}
```

> However, the compiler complains that TestInterface.NON_CONST_B is final --

---

But it in fact **is** final whether you explicitly declare it to be or not since it is declared in an interface. You can't have non-final variables (non-constants) in an interface. It's also public and static whether or not it has been explicitly declared as such.

Per the [JLS 9.3 Interface Field (Constant) Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is **implicitly** public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, all variables declared in an `interface` are `public static final` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared in interface are always public static final by default in java. Interface variables are static because Java interfaces cannot be instantiated in their own right; the value of the variable must be assigned in a static context in which no instance exists. The final modifier ensures the value assigned to the interface variable is a true constant that cannot be re-assigned by program code.

Answer (score 0):

As all answers saying that by default all the variables declared in Interface are static final variables.

FYI, you can not declare a `static` method in interface. You can find the reason in [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858393/1686291)
however, you can declare `Inner Class` in an interface that can contain `static` methods and non static and non final variables.